# Changing the type of an object inside a method?

Tags: c#, casting, polymorphism

First off, this is not my code.  I'm curious what everyone thinks about changing the type of an object inside of a method then modifying the properties of the cast type. I wanted to use composition to build up a patient, but this is the recommend path.  I'm probably wrong which is why I wanted 3rd party feedback.  Or maybe we just have different coding styles...

```
    // Person/Patient Builder
public static void BuildUpPersonOrPatient(Person person, Dictionary<string, string> row)
        {
    person.FirstName = row["FirstName"];
    person.LastName = row["LastName"];

    Patient patient = person as Patient;

    if (patient != null)
    {
        patient.PatientID = row["PatientID"];
    }
}
```

for reference

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Patient : Person
{
    public string PatientID { get; set; }
}
```

//
//

Comment: In C# you can't change the type of an object (an object only exist at runtime) you can test the type (and cast) as you do but you are not chaning the type

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It stead of having a static method the basically does what polymorphism could do for you use polymorphism.

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }

    public virtual void InitializeFromDictionary(Dictionary<string, string> row)
    {
        FirstName = row["FirstName"];
        LastName = row["LastName"];
    }
}

public class Patient : Person
{
    public string PatientID { get; private set; }
    public override void InitializeFromDictionary(Dictionary<string, string> row)
    {
       base.InitializeFromDictionary(row)
       PatientID = row["PatientID"];
    }
}
```

and then where ever you call

```
BuildUpPersonOrPatient(p,row);
```

do this instead

```
p.InitialieFromDictionary(row);
```

I've added an access modifier to the setters because unless you have a reason to be able to change those fields from outside the object you should encapsulate the possibility of chaning the state of an object. (It's surprising how seldom you have a modeling reason for that and not just a "for conviniece" reason)